# Automating S3 bucket creation to store tf.state file prior to terraform execution

Tags: amazon-s3, automation, terraform

Is there a solution that generates an s3 bucket for storing tf.state file prior to terraform execution?

Meaning I don't want to create an s3 bucket on the console and specify it in the backend.tf, I want the s3 bucket to be automatically created and the tf.state file stored on this automatically created s3 bucket.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Yes, the solution is you have a second TF code that creates such a bucket.

Comment: But for me to have a backend.tf, I need to already have an s3 bucket created and specified in the backend.tf. Even if I create s3 bucket resource in the configuration. the tf.state file will still be stored in the s3 bucket stipulated in the backend.tf, not newly created one. Or am I wrong? Please explain how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have a shell script that checks the given state bucket exists if not then it creates the bucket first before executing the TF code.

You can use

```
aws s3 mb s3://bucketName --region us-west-2
```